# bind a 1parameter function to a callback with 2 parameters function avoiding error TS6133

Tags: typescript

I am sure i could find the answer but i don't use the good wording for search sorry about that.

I am in typescript on nodejs. 
I cannot change typescript compilation settings as i am working in a team.

I use a library that has a callback definition like :
    `(arg1:string, arg2:number)=> void`

I have a function that do something with definition like : 
    `(arg:number)=>void`

how do i bind the function without having a error :
    `error TS6133: 'variable' is declared but its value is never read.`

here is a code that i wrote until now:

```
class MyClass{
    private libInstance : ExternalLibClass;

    constructor() {
        this.libInstance = new ExternalLibClass();
        this.libInstance.on('event1', this.functionA);
        this.libInstance.on('event2', this.functionB);
    }

    private this.functionA (num : number): void {
        // do something
        console.log(num);
    }

    private this.functionB (ignore :string, num : number) : void {
        this.functionA(num);
    }
}
```

when I compile I got the Error on function B:

```
`error TS6133: 'ignore' is declared but its value is never read.`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer in [the github TypeScript issue 9459](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458)

if you prefix your variable name by undescore the rule TS6133 does not apply.

```
class MyClass{
    private libInstance : ExternalLibClass;

    constructor() {
        this.libInstance = new ExternalLibClass();
        this.libInstance.on('event1', this.functionA);
        this.libInstance.on('event2', this.functionB);
    }

    private this.functionA (num : number): void {
        // do something
        console.log(num);
    }

    private this.functionB (_ignore :string, num : number) : void {
        this.functionA(num);
    }
}
```